# Debian squeeze: SSH login works fine, SFTP login returns a Failed password error

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, sftp

I'm currently trying to setup SFTP on debian using openssh. 
I can still login with all my users using ssh, but as soon as i'm trying to login using an SFTP client like filezilla i'm getting an failed password error.
Even the root user returns a password failed error 
I've already set `PasswordAuthentication yes` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config so that's not the problem

it did work before i updated the openssh-server package

Comment: Have you tested with `scp`?

Comment: no haven't tested it. but i need to get it to work with sftp.

Comment: I'm not saying you must just use `scp`, I'm asking whether it works or not. Debugging is about narrowing down the problem.

Comment: I've now tried it with cyberduck on it works fine; must be a problem with filezilla

Comment: Did you select the "SSH File Transfer Protocol" option FileZilla? The "FTP over implicit/explicit TLS/SSL" options are a completely different protocol.

Comment: yeah selected SFTP- ssh file transfer protocol. the weird thing is that it was working before but stopped working today. so i thought it had something to do with the changes i made to /etc/ssh/sshd_config. but even after reverting it back to the original version it was still throwing the same error

Comment: You might try setting `LogLevel  DEBUG` into /etc/ssh/sshd_config  and restart/reload ssh server. It should provide you more details about why it is failing.